# Inequality using Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^+$, prove that $$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{c+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+b}}\leq \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)} $$

Hi everyone, I've been trying to do this exercise but any method that I tried has failed. First I tried to use $v=(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}},\sqrt{\frac{b}{c+a}},\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+b}})$ and $w=(1,1,1)$ (the most obvious) but didn't work. Then I did this $$LHS= \frac{\sqrt{a(c+a)(a+b)}+\sqrt{b(b+c)(a+b)}+\sqrt{c(b+c)(c+a)}}{\sqrt{(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)}}\leq \frac{\sqrt{(a(a+b)+b(b+c)+c(c+a))(c+a+a+b+b+c)}}{\sqrt{(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)}} = \frac{\sqrt{2((a+b+c)^2-(ab+bc+ac))(a+b+c)}}{\sqrt{(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)}}$$

Using the fact that $\sqrt{ax}+\sqrt{by}+\sqrt{cz} \leq \sqrt{(a+b+c)(x+y+z)}$ but I don't know if I'm not looking something. If someone can give me a hint I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood what **tong_nor** meant so I want to write it in details.
So treat this answer as a more detailed version of the **tong_nor** answer.

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives us that:

(1) $(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2)(b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2) \geq (a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3)^2$

If we put here $a_i = \sqrt {a_i}$, $b_i = \sqrt {b_i}$ we get:

(2) $(a_1 + a_2 + a_3)(b_1 + b_2 + b_3) \geq (\sqrt {a_1b_1} + \sqrt{a_2b_2} + \sqrt{a_3b_3})^2$

Now in (2) we put:

$a_1 = a$, $a_2 = b$, $a_3 = c$
$b_1 = \frac{1}{b+c}$, $b_2 = \frac{1}{c+a}$, $b_3 = \frac{1}{a+b}$

So we get:

(3) $(a+b+c) (\frac{1}{b+c} + \frac{1}{c+a} + \frac{1}{a+b}) \geq (\sqrt {\frac{a}{b+c}} + \sqrt {\frac{b}{c+a}} + \sqrt {\frac{c}{a+b}})^2$

We take square root in (3) and reverse the sides:

(4) $ \sqrt {\frac{a}{b+c}} + \sqrt {\frac{b}{c+a}} + \sqrt {\frac{c}{a+b}} \leq \sqrt {(a+b+c) (\frac{1}{b+c} + \frac{1}{c+a} + \frac{1}{a+b}) } $

Now back to (2) where we put $a_i = \frac{x_i^2}{y_i}$ and $b_i = y_i$

So we get:

(5) $(\frac{x_1^2}{y_1} + \frac{x_2^2}{y_2} + \frac{x_3^2}{y_3}) (y_1+y_2+y_3)\geq (x_1+x_2 + x_3)^2$

Now in (5) we put:

$x_1 = a, x_2 = b, x_3 = c$
$y_1 = ab, y_2 = bc, y_3 = ca$

and we obtain the following:

(6) $ ( \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} ) (ab+bc+ca) \geq (a+b+c)^2  $   i.e.

(7) $ ( \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} )  \geq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{(ab+bc+ca)}  $

Now we will prove that:

(8) $(\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}+\frac{1}{a+b}) \le \frac{3}{2}\frac{a+b+c}{ab+bc+ca}$

Let's rewrite the inequality (8). We multiply both sides by $ab+bc+ac$. Then:

$$LHS=\frac{ab+bc+ac}{b+c}+\frac{ab+bc+ac}{c+a}+\frac{ab+bc+ac}{a+b} = \frac{a(b+c)+bc}{b+c}+\frac{b(a+c)+ac}{a+c}+\frac{c(b+a)+ab}{a+b} = a+\frac{bc}{b+c}+b+\frac{ac}{c+a}+c+\frac{ab}{a+b}$$

Now we subtract $(a+b+c)$ from both sides. This shows that:
$$(8) \Leftrightarrow \frac{bc}{b+c}+\frac{ac}{a+c}+\frac{ab}{a+b}\leq \frac{1}{2}(a+b+c) $$

Taking into account that $4ab\leq (a+b)^2$ we get:

$$\frac{bc}{b+c}+\frac{ac}{a+c}+\frac{ab}{a+b}\leq \frac{(b+c)^2}{4(b+c)}+\frac{(c+a)^2}{4(c+a)}+\frac{(a+b)^2}{4(a+b)} = \frac{1}{2}(a+b+c) $$

OK, this completes the proof of (8).

So now from (4) and by using (8) and then (7) we get:
(9)  $ \sqrt {\frac{a}{b+c}} + \sqrt {\frac{b}{c+a}} + \sqrt {\frac{c}{a+b}} \leq \sqrt {(a+b+c) \cdot \frac{3}{2}\frac{(a+b+c)}{ab+bc+ca}} \leq \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a})}$

That's all we wanted to prove.

Comment: Oh man I spend all my weekend working and all afternoon trying to use correctly the tong_nor's answer with my friends, but was impossible. Thank you so much! I'll write the intermediate steps now :)

Comment: It's very twisted this one. tong_nor was way too short IMHO. But he found the solution very quickly so... respect. I am glad that my deciphering effort helps :)

Comment: I was re-reading my own answer today I don't see how we can prove (8). I will have to think some more. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the prove of (8). I'll edit your answer :)

Comment: @SebastiánMolina Thanks, that proof is quite elegant. I was trying hard but did not manage to prove (8) today.

Answer (score 3):

By Cauchy-Schwarz
$$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{c+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+b}}\leq\sqrt{(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}+\frac{1}{a+b}\right)}$$
and
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\ge\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca}$$
so it suffices to prove
$$\left(\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}+\frac{1}{a+b}\right) \le \frac{3}{2}\frac{a+b+c}{ab+bc+ca}$$
if my calculations are correct this is equivalent to $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\ge 0$

Comment: How did you get the second inequality?

Comment: I used a different version of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%96_%E2%80%94_%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE (see at the bottom, marked as "olympiad")

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint. You can denote:

$x=\frac{a}{b}, y=\frac{b}{c}, z=\frac{c}{a}$
Then we have: $xyz=1$ i.e. $z = \frac{1}{xy}$

Then use that:  $\sqrt \frac{a}{b+c} = \sqrt \frac{1}{b/a+c/a} = \sqrt \frac{1}{1/x + z} $ and do analogically for the other terms in the LHS.
Then if you use that $z = \frac{1}{xy}$ it boils down to an inequality containing just $x$ and $y$.

Let me see if something good will come out of this, I think it will.

Comment: Hm, seems nothing good comes out. I get swamped in unpleasant calculations.

Comment: Me too, I tried to expand the LHS but I only get unpleasant terms.

Comment: This means there's some simpler trick which we just don't see.