# Prove this inequality (possibly Cauchy-Schwarz related)

Tags: inequality

Prove that if $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers then:

$\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}+\frac{1}{a+b} \le \frac{3}{2}\frac{a+b+c}{ab+bc+ca}$

Is this true and how can we prove it? I guess it should be something relatively easy.
I came across this while working on another problem here:
[Inequality using Cauchy-Schwarz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697427/inequality-using-cauchy-schwarz/1697902#1697902)

Comment: It think it is helpful to use $(x+y+z)^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+xz)$.

Comment: Alright. I did so, too. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is equivalent to $$(a^2-c^2)(a-c)b+(a-b)(a^2-b^2)c+a(b^2-c^2)(b-c)\geq 0$$
which is positive.

Comment: Thanks, I will verify your calculations. Thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, it is this indeed. I got: $a^3 b + a^3 c + b^3 a + b^3 c + c^3 a + c^3 b - 2 a^2 b c  - 2 a b^2 c - 2 a b c^2 $ which is the same as your expression. But the representation you showed is the key. No idea how you found this so quickly, it took me about 2 hours just to get $a^3 b + a^3 c + b^3 a + b^3 c + c^3 a + c^3 b - 2 a^2 b c  - 2 a b^2 c - 2 a b c^2 $. And even from here I am not sure I would have been able to come up with your representation.